# How to use phantomjs?

Tags: phantomjs

I would like to learn phantomjs, but i can`t find good tutorial. I have 2 questions:

1. where is problem in following code (need to capture label of button and write to file):

   ```
   var page = require('webpage').create();
   var fs = require('fs');

   page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
       phantom.outputEncoding = "utf-8";
       console.log(msg);
   };

   page.open("http://vk.com", function(status) {
       if ( status === "success" ) {
           page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
               page.evaluate(function() {
                   var str = $("#quick_login_button").text();
                   f = fs.open("ololo.txt", "w");
                   f.writeLine(str);
                   f.close();
                   console.log("done");
               });
               phantom.exit();
           });
       }
   });
   ```
2. what tutorial in phantomjs you can advice to me? (not from official site)

Comment: There are lots of useful examples shipped with phantomjs - I'd start by working through those

Answer (score 2):

Because execution is sandboxed, the web page has no access to the phantom objects.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    phantom.outputEncoding = "utf-8";
    console.log(msg);
};

page.open("http://vk.com", function(status) {
    if ( status === "success" ) {
        page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
            var str = page.evaluate(function() {
                return $("#quick_login_button").text();        
            });
            f = fs.open("ololo.txt", "w");
            f.writeLine(str);
            f.close();
            console.log("done");

            phantom.exit();
        });
    }
});
```

PhantomJS comes with a lot of included examples. Take a look [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Examples).